# Could not find matching function from the SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to use transfer learning on my own dataset structured as:

```
dataset
    healthy
    unhealthy
```

First, I loaded these images off disk using [image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory).
Then, as good practice I split the dataset on train (80%), validation (10%) and test(10%) when developing the model.

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 244
img_width = 244

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  image_path,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  image_path,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(val_ds)
test_dataset = val_ds.take(val_batches // 5)
val_ds = val_ds.skip(val_batches // 5)
```

Then, when I'm going to train a simple model with Transfer Learning using the dataset we just prepared.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/cropnet/feature_vector/cassava_disease_V1/1'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_ds, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I'm getting the below error:

> ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
> Positional arguments (3 total):
> * Tensor("image:0", shape=(None, 244, 244, 3), dtype=float32)
> * False
> * 0.99
> Keyword arguments: {}
>
> ```
> Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
>
> Option 1:
>   Positional arguments (3 total):
>     * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='image')
>     * False
>     * 0.99
>   Keyword arguments: {}
>
> Option 2:
>   Positional arguments (3 total):
>     * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='image')
>     * False
>     * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
>   Keyword arguments: {}
>
> Option 3:
>   Positional arguments (3 total):
>     * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='image')
>     * True
>     * 0.99
>   Keyword arguments: {}
>
> Option 4:
>   Positional arguments (3 total):
>     * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='image')
>     * True
>     * TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='batch_norm_momentum')
>   Keyword arguments: {}
> ```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`cropnet/feature_vector/cassava_disease_V1` expects input of shape `[batch size, 224, 224, 3]`.
For more information visit the [Tensorflow hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/cropnet/feature_vector/cassava_disease_V1/1)

Change img_height and img_width to 224

```
img_height = 224
img_width = 224
```